# force LI to appear on next of previous item

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have five `LI` in a `DIV` and `LI` max width is 90 pixel and the parent container max-width is 360px, and I am trying to show the first three `div` and the next `LI` should be hidden and parent should add scroller so user can swipe from left to right to see the remaining `LI`, but its breaking to next line, how do I force `LI` and avoid breaking to second line?

Here is working [JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/xzc7khk0/)

```css
.spotlight_graphs {
  bottom: 30px;
  clear: both;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 360px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#cbcbcb;
  overflow:auto;
  padding:10px;
}
.spotlight_graphs > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align:center;
}
.spotlight_graphs > ul > li {
  max-width: 90px;
  width: 33%;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:#dec8c8;
  height:100px;
  margin:0 5px 5px 0;
  border:1px solid #333333;
}
.spotlight_graphs > ul > li > .graph_detail {
  color: #404040;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="spotlight_graphs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="graph_detail"> This is dummy title </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="graph_detail"> This is dummy title </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="graph_detail"> This is dummy title </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="graph_detail"> This is dummy title </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="graph_detail"> This is dummy title </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this is same, I want to hide the last two items and move them to one line

Comment: sorry i forget to update..check this one https://jsfiddle.net/xzc7khk0/2/

Comment: yes, exactly this is what I was looking for, please post it as an answer as well

Comment: ok give me a min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have scroll bar, apply `overflow` property. As you needed horizontal scroll bar then you should use `overflow-x:scroll` and give width to ul so your li will be in one row.

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xzc7khk0/2/). To read more about overflow, check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)